# R Convert a String<List> to List

Tags: r, string, list, file-read

I am importing a column from a file. The column is formed using a collect_list function. So every entry looks like follows:

```
[1,5,10]
[27,30,1,33,40]
[1,2,8,20,30,50,...]
```

I am trying to read this column into R and convert every row into a list. When I read I get a string for every row of the form:

```
"[1,5,10]"
```

What should I do to read this column into a list? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That's effectively streaming JSON and can be imported as such:

```r
text <- '[1,5,10]
[27,30,1,33,40]
[1,2,8,20,30,50]'

l <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(text), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

str(l)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : int [1:3] 1 5 10
#>  $ : int [1:5] 27 30 1 33 40
#>  $ : int [1:6] 1 2 8 20 30 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use `str_split` from the `stringr` package. If `df` is your data frame and `data` is the variable name:

```
library("stringr")
df$data = gsub(pattern = "(\\[|\\])", replacement = "", x = df$x)
list = str_split(string = df$data, pattern = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have exactly in mind but if you import your data into a 
data.frame and want to have a column with list values you can use `strsplit`:

```
dd = structure(list(x = c("[1,5,10]", "[27,30,1,33,40]", "[1,2,8,20,30,50]")), .Names = c("x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:3)

dd$y = strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', dd$x), ",")
```

if you want `dd$y` to have numeric data instead you can also use:

```
dd$y = lapply(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', dd$x), ","), as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
> str(dd)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "[1,5,10]" "[27,30,1,33,40]" "[1,2,8,20,30,50]"
 $ y:List of 3
  ..$ : num  1 5 10
  ..$ : num  27 30 1 33 40
  ..$ : num  1 2 8 20 30 50
```